# Экспорт и импорт проекта Eclipse

Tags: export, android, eclipse

На "компьютере 1" создал проект Android Application.
Как его правильно перенести на "компьютер 2"?

Пробовал делать Export -> Import
Но почему-то xml-файлы после импорта оказываются пустыми, в том числе manifest.

Comment: А копировать весь проект целиком на другой комп, а затем Import/Existing Projects Into Workspace не прокатывает тоже??

Comment: @MDJHD прав. Достаточно скопировать весь проект целиком на новый компьютер, так как вы не меняете IDE (на пример с Eclipse на IDEA).